# Argumentless nodemon command in npm project does not run value of "main" from package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, nodemon

I have an npm project with the following folder structure:

```
project
├── node_modules
│   └── (node_modles folders)
├── server.js
├── index.js
├── index.html
├── package.json
└── package-lock.json
```

My `index.js` is my front end JavaScript code of this little Web app. And my `server.js` is the back end. I'm using nodemon (version 2.0.16) to run my `server.js` file, which is a simple Express app:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.listen(4000, () => {console.log('Listening on port 4000')})
```

To run my server, I run `nodemon server.js` in my terminal, and my Express app runs correctly. However, the Nodemon docs say:

> If you have a package.json file for your app, you can omit the main
> script entirely and nodemon will read the package.json for the main
> property and use that value as the app ([ref](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/14)).

So, I figure that if my `package.json` file looks like this

```
{
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1"
  }
}
```

then I should be able to just run `nodemon` instead of `nodemon server.js`, and everything should work the same. However, this is not the case. When I simply run `nodemon` with this setup, it's apparently trying to run my `index.js` file regardless of what I have for `"main"` in my `package.json` file. Can anyone explain why I can't just run nodemon without arguments in this case?

Comment: Isn't this something you should bring up on the [Nodemon issues list](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues)?

Comment: Per your suggestion, I just posted an issue on the Nodemon issues list. But I think it's still appropriate here, as it might be working by design. It just wasn't very explicit in the docs. https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/2051

Answer (score 0):

It appears that if I delete `index.js`, running the no-argument `nodemon` command works as expected. However, if there is a file named `index.js` at the root of the project, then that file will get run no matter what I put for `"main"` in `package.json`.

I'm not sure if this is working-as-designed or if it was intended to have the "main" value ignored like this. I couldn't find a mention of the precedence in the docs.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. You should [report it](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/new/choose)

Comment: FYI the [code here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/main/lib/config/load.js#L19) doesn't appear to do what it says it should

Comment: @Phil, you are right.  `findAppScript` is assigned to `options` [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/176c4a6bed989fe94f103c905e5eee341d26794d/lib/config/load.js#L84) then passed as the `exec` options [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/176c4a6bed989fe94f103c905e5eee341d26794d/lib/config/load.js#L239) which means it's too late to impose the "main" logic [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/176c4a6bed989fe94f103c905e5eee341d26794d/lib/config/exec.js#L95-L96) because we only do `execFromPackage` if `options.script` is falsey.  It's a bug.